# else if is not printing the console value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have JavaScript code which displays a multi coffee value.
If I am trying to display a single value coffee, its not going inside the else if.
I modified existing code but getting an undefined error.
Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
var multCoffees = false;
var singleCoffee = false;
if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    multCoffees = true;
}
if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    singleCoffee = true;
}
if (apptTimeCell) {
    apptTimeHTML = MyDay.dish(allData, multCoffees, singleCoffee);
    apptTimeCell.innerHTML = apptTimeHTML;
} else {
    apptTimeCell = Util.cep("span", {
        className: "appt-time"
    });
    patientRowTD.insertBefore(apptTimeCell, patCell);
}
dish: function (allData, multCoffees, singleCoffee) {
    if (multCoffees) {
        var htmlArr = [];
        htmlArr.push(allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.MNEMONIC, "</span>");
        console.log("multiCoffee" + allData.PROVIDER_MNEMONIC);
        return htmlArr.join("");
    } else if (singleCoffee) {
        console.log("inside if" + allData.PROVIDER_MNEMONIC);
        var htmlArr = [];
        htmlArr.push(allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.PROVIDER_MNEMONIC, "</span>");
        console.log("singleCoffee" + allData.PROVIDER_MNEMONIC);
        return htmlArr.join("");
    } else {
        return allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY;
    }
},
```

Working code:

```
var multCoffees = false;
if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    multCoffees = true;
}
if (apptTimeCell) {
    apptTimeHTML = MyDay.dish(allData, multCoffees);
    apptTimeCell.innerHTML = apptTimeHTML;
} else {
    apptTimeCell = Util.cep("span", {
        className: "appt-time"
    });
    patientRowTD.insertBefore(apptTimeCell, patCell);
}
dish: function (allData, multCoffees) {
    if (multCoffees) {
        var htmlArr = [];
        htmlArr.push(allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.MNEMONIC, "</span>");
        console.log("multiCoffee" + allData.PROVIDER_MNEMONIC);
        return htmlArr.join("");
    } else {
        return allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose Coffees.length is 2.  You do this...

```
if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    multCoffees = true;
}
```

...and 2 > 1, so now multCoffees is true, but then you do this, which checks the same thing...

```
if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    singleCoffee = true;
}
```

and, since 2 > 1 still, now BOTH multCoffees AND singleCoffee are true.  So when you try to do

```
if (multCoffees) {
   ...
} else if (singleCoffee) {
   ...
}
```

the first if branch is true, so it is executed, and the else branch is thus ignored (despite also being true).  You probably meant to instead start with

```
if (Coffees.length == 1) {
    singleCoffee = true;
} else if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    multCoffees = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...i could not understand...can u pls update my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mCwcv/

Comment: You are checking the same thing twice; the first time you check it, you set multCoffees to be true; the second time you check it, you ALSO set singleCoffee to be true -- multCoffees is still true.

Answer (score 3):

replace your first two ifs with this block:

```
if (Coffees.length == 1) {
    singleCoffee = true; 
}
else if(Coffees.length > 1){
   multCoffees = true;
}
```

and then try it again!